# Association dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

What is the best way to implement something like a board in pinterest (a collection of objects) in rails. I am trying to come with it, it seems more like an array implementation. 
Here's my logic for the associations : User have many collections, user have many pins , collections belongs to user.

User class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins, through: :collections
  has_many :collections  
end
```

Pins class

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :collections 

end
```

Collections class

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So now here's my confusion, how to implement a controller that will allow me to create a collection and inside this collection object, create or push pins and save them as another object for the current_user. Hope I'm making sense

Here's the controller

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @collection = current_user.collections.new(params[:collection])
     #this where i'm confused , if it an array , how to implement it , to push or   create a pin object inside ?
   end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested attributes for this.

Check this http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/.

Basically what you need is:

```
# collection model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pins

# view, see also nested_form in github
f.fields_for :pins
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `has_many_through` association. See section 2.4 on the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections  
end 

class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, through: :pinnings
end

class Pinning < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pin
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pins, through: :pinnings
end
```